# reading from binary and stocking on double array of char

Tags: c, arrays, file, io, binary

i have to get a specific 2bytes  value from a binary file, inside the loop printing r15[i] show the correct value (0000, fff6, ....), but outside the loop, iterating all over r15 again show only one value 0100.
reading from the file i done byte by byte and i concatenate the two values values and save it in r15[counter]. So my question, is this the correct way of reading a 2bytes value from a binary file?, and what's making the array r15 to change its value at the end of the loop?

```
  char **r15;
  r15 = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *)*50000);

   for(i=0; i<50000; i++) r15[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*5);

 fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb");

 if (fp == NULL)    {
    printf("fail opning file\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}        

 int i; 
 int check;
 char r[5];
 unsigned int counter=1;


  while((check=getc(fp)) != EOF){
      fseek(fp,32*counter-2, SEEK_SET);

      fread(buffer,1,2,fp);

      sprintf (r, "%02x%02x", buffer[0], buffer[1]);
      r15[counter-1]=r;
      printf("r15[%d] %s\n",counter-1,r15[counter-1]);

      counter++;
  }

// result here diffrent than printing inside while loop
for(i=0;i<counter-1;i++) printf("r15[%d] %s\n",i,r15[i]);
```

edit1:  still after changing r size to 5, the values printed inside the loop are different than those printed outside.
edit2: i found a solution by replacing:

```
   r15[counter]=r; or strcpy(r15[counter],r);
```

by this:

```
   r15[counter][0]=r[0];
   r15[counter][1]=r[1];
   r15[counter][2]=r[2];
   r15[counter][3]=r[3];
```

but still i don't get it why it didn't work with strcpy strncpy and r15[counter]=r

Comment: "since printing r15 inside the loop show the correct values" is irrelevant. It MUST be 5 large to hold 4 chararcters, and the printf will append a null character, so it needs to be declared as 5 large. You have just been lucky here.

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

```
 r15[counter-1]=r;
```

You assign the address of r to the array, but you want to assign the value of r to the array, so use:

```
strcpy( r15[counter-1], r);
```

...and `r` must be 5 large to include the terminating null.

Also when allocating the storage you must allocate 5 bytes for each string. Please read about strings in your book on C.

Comment: when i use strcpy i get  warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’, and even after changing r size nothing changes

Comment: Add: `#include <string.h>`. Did you allocate 5 bytes with malloc for each array element?

Comment: i did include string and changed the sizes

Comment: I ran your program and it runs fine with my suggestions. `counter` must be initialized to 0 and you must not subtract that 1 from counter.

Comment: i changed the counter to zero, still no luck, but i found the solution with replacing `r15[counter]=r; with r15[counter][0]=r[0] ...`

Comment: Yes, Hamza, that is about the same as `strcpy` as now you are copying the _contents_ of `r`'.